# Do we need "cloud recommendations"

Tags: discussion, site-proposal

There is a Stack Exchange site called "Software Recommendations".

Since we are living in a cloud world full of services for every aspect of live: do we need a new Stack Exchange site called "**cloud recommendations**" or "**service recommendations**"?

Topics in that site could be about:

- Is there a cloud service that...
- How to combine Cloud services A and B?
- Which free services can I use in order to do...
- Condiguration recommendations for cloud services?
- API vs UI

Comment: New sites are proposed on area51

Answer (score 12):

After Software Recommendations and Hardware Recommendations, it was decided [not to have more "Recommendations" SE sites](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24050/41556) for the foreseeable future.

I don't think "Cloud Recommendations" would work in the SE model, which is aimed at providing answers that will remain useful for a long time. The properties of cloud services can be changed at any time, at the desire of the company that offers the cloud service. This makes lasting answers a difficult proposition.

If you really want to try, you could go to [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com) and propose such a site. But I doubt it'll fly, for the reasons mentioned above.